# Arrays created with new?

Tags: javascript

Why is the behavior different for javascript arrays created with new?

```
(new Array(10)).length
```

10

```
var x = 0;
(new Array(10)).forEach(function(){ console.log(++x) });
```

: nothing - Why?

```
var x = 0;
[undefined,undefined,undefined].forEach( function(){console.log(++x)});
```

1

2

3

Comment: Sparse arrays are confusing in Javascript. Try to avoid them.

Comment: An alternative would be this: `Array.apply(null, Array(10)).forEach(....`

Comment: Try this (to see that it's not *really* an issue with `new Array`): `var a = []; a[10] = "done"; a.forEach(console.log.bind(console))`. It's in the definition of `forEach` and `map` to skip "non existent elements".